# Logging hits only with varnishncsa

Tags: varnish

By default, varnishncsa logs both hits and misses. As I'm already logging misses in my back-end server logs, I'm looking to only log hits in varnishncsa to remove duplication and keep logfile size down. Has anyone managed to do this?

I'm running Varnish 3.0.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 Server x64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my varnish instances I include an 'X-Cache' header that says HIT or MISS as appropriate.  With that you can just look for that in 'TxHeader':

```
varnishncsa -c -m "TxHeader:X-Cache: HIT"
```

To add this header you can add something like this in your .vcl file:

```
sub vcl_deliver {
      if (obj.hits > 0) {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
      } else {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
      }
}
```

Comment: Nice. That works. I'd been using Varnish:hitmiss to add 'hit' and 'miss' to the logs, but varnishncsa wouldn't allow me to reference it in it the '-m' parameter.

Using resp.http.X-Cache, the value of X-Cache gets echoed back to the client. Is there a way of achieving this without using visible HTTP headers?

Comment: You could potentially remove the header in vcl_deliver. Not sure if it would still be available to varnishcsa or not, but it might be. I strip a load of `X-*` headers in vcl_deliver except for my own IPs (useful for debugging purposes).